# ASP.Net MVC 3 - No Details redirection after succesfull creation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

After creating an object, my page won't continue to the details page, although the object is correctly created.

Following is my code:

```
Function Create(ByVal collection As FormCollection) As ActionResult
        Dim _NieuweKlant As New Domain.Slave.Klant
        Try

            If ModelState.IsValid Then

                TryUpdateModel(_NieuweKlant, collection)

                _NieuweKlant.UpdatedON = Now
                _NieuweKlant.LaatsteWijzigingGebruiker = Now
                '_NieuweKlant.LaatsteActie = Now

                KlantService.createKlant(_NieuweKlant)
                KlantService.SaveKlant()

                'check validstate

                Return Details(_NieuweKlant.KlantID)
            End If

        Catch ex As System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException
            Dim Errors = ex.EntityValidationErrors.First
            For Each propertyError In Errors.ValidationErrors
                ModelState.AddModelError(propertyError.PropertyName, propertyError.ErrorMessage)
            Next
            Return View(_NieuweKlant)
        Catch ex As System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException
            Return View(_NieuweKlant)
        Catch Ex As Exception
            '       Console.Out.Write("Bericht:" & vbCrLf & Ex.Message)
            '   Console.Out.Write("InnerException: " & vbCrLf & Ex.InnerException.ToString)
            Return View()
        End Try
    End Function
```

I also already tried RedirectToAction and when debugging there doesn't seem to be a mistake. It just won't redirect or go to the other action.

Comment: Did you get an exception? If not, what view is being rendered?

Comment: try return View("Details",_NieuweKlant.KlantId) instead of Return Details(_NieuweKlant.KlantId)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect you need to use `RedirectToAction`, like this:

```
Return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = _NieuweKlant.KlantID })
```

As a second argument we are specifying the id action parameter so that when the page redirects this parameter gets populated:

```
Function Details(ByVal Id As Integer) As ActionResult
```

Of course this redirection will happen only if no exception is thrown.

This being said if you are invoking the `Create` action with AJAX things might be different in terms of *redirect*.

Comment: I know, i have tried RedirectToAction already, but it didn't work.
I changed it back to Return View(object), because that to normally works, except now :)

Comment: @NicoJuicy, a RedirectToAction should work. What do you mean when you say that it doesn't work? What do you see in FireBug? What are the sequence of HTTP requests being executed?

Comment: There was a custom validation that didn't get returned in the view and then it resetted. Removing the validation fixed it.
Also, although your answer could be correct, it's not the answer to my specific problem.
But i'll accept it, because it is the best answer.